# How do boxed traits interact with memory when using match in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, traits

I have the following function:

```rust
fn get_person(type: PersonType, age: u8) -> Result<Box<dyn Person>> {
    Ok(match type {
        PersonType::Thin => Box::new(ThinPerson::new(age)),
        PersonType::Fat => Box::new(FatPerson::new(age)),
    })
}
```

Let's assume `ThinPerson` and `FatPerson` both implement `Person` trait. And `FatPerson` struct requires a much larger memory footprint.

I believe during `Box::new(...)`, `ThinPerson`/`FatPerson` structs are first created on the stack and then *pushed off* into the heap once boxed.

Initially, I had only `ThinPerson` as an arm to the `match`. Once I added `FatPerson`, I noticed the stack usage has increased even if the code never traverses the `PersonType::Fat` arm.

Can someone please explain why? Does the `match` somehow looks at *all* the arms and allocates stack space according to the largest struct it finds?

As a secondary question, how would I avoid this stack bloat? I understand "placement by return" RFC is still in the design phase and I cannot step outside safe Rust.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you measuring "stack bloat"? I'd suspect that an optimized build would create the boxed structs directly on heap. But if it does not: Add separate functions for each type that return `-> Box<dyn Person>` and are marked as `#[inline(never)]`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, but the behavior is not specific to `match`. Generally each *function* (that is not inlined) will allocate a stack frame (by increasing the stack pointer) that accounts for the whole execution of the function (not counting nested functions that are not inlined). There is no cost to allocating more stack space if you don't use it. "Stack bloat" is only really a concern unless you are in a stack-constrained scenario (recursion or embedded usually).

Comment: @kmdreko So, IIUC, the function's stack size has to be chosen before it executes, which means it has to be large enough to fit everything it might ever use.

Comment: Yep, I'm working in a stack-constrained runtime. And my detection of the bloat is not anything intelligent. I have used most of the stack and I notice adding that Fat arm will cause access violations, and removing it, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the `match` somehow looks at all the arms and allocates stack space according to the largest struct it finds?

It must; stack space is allocate statically. Theoretically it *could* allocate dynamically, but this is way too hard and AFAIK proper alignment is still not supported in LLVM.

> As a secondary question, how would I avoid this stack bloat? I understand "placement by return" RFC is still in the design phase and I cannot step outside safe Rust.

As @Caesar suggested, make the constructor function return a `Box` (not necessarily `Box<<dyn Person>`, can be `Box<Self>`). This way the stack space will be allocated only if it will be actually called. It is also possible that if the constructor function will be inlined LLVM will write in place. If not, you can make it take `&mut Self` and write to that instead of returning `Self`, and pass it a zeroed `FatPerson` or something like that. The problem is the return of `Self`, LLVM can optimize the write itself quite easily.